# Jquery update css file property with json array class names

Tags: jquery, css, json

https://jsfiddle.net/5vue1buj/9/

I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the css properties through jquery with the values listed in here:

```
trials = [
    { 
    values : ["blue", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow"],
    triangle:["triangle-1", "triangle-2","triangle-4","triangle-3","triangle-1"],
    response : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    { 
    values : ["red"......etc],
     etc
    etc
    }
];
```

the css is stored in myFile.css

What I want to do is every 5 (or so) seconds, the index will increment and update the different shapes accordingly. For example, shape with `.triangle-1` will update from white to blue, then after 5 seconds shape of class `triangle-2` would update to red, etc etc. After it gets to the end, so index 4, it will pause (but that's not part of where I'm struggling).

Something like

```
currentIndex = 0;

trials[currentIndex].colors[currentIndex]
currentIndex ++;
```

to get the value of the colors and className, but I'm not sure how to update the color.

Comment: First of all, you have a syntax issue - should be trials = { ... } instead of the [] you are using. You are defining an Object with keys and properties, not an array.

Comment: @TimMcClure thanks for catching that Tim - wrote it incorrectly, just fixed

Comment: Can you provide relevant HTML or a working jsfiddle?

Comment: @TimMcClure I just added a fiddle and updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is just to use the jQuery selectors and css methods.

So, something like the following might do it, it's not the prettiest but it can get you started -

```
var trials = {
    colors : ["blue", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow"],
    classNames: ["1", "2", "3", "2", "4"]
};

TimedChange(trials, 0);

function TimedChange(classColours, iteration)
{
    ChangeClassColour(classColours.className[iteration], classColours.colors[iteration]);

    setTimeout(TimedChange(classColours, iteration + 1), 1000);
}

function ChangeClassColour(className, colour)
{
    // you'd set whatever css styles you need to change
    jQuery("." + className).css({ color: colour, background-color: colour });
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `classColours.colors[iteration]`^^